# How can I get the actual path of a picked image using CrossMedia in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, filepath, plugin.media.crossmedia

I need to get the actual path of a picked image using `CrossMedia` library .

When I tryd to get the file path using `File.Path` I get a temporary path not the actual path.

It also copies the image and gives the image a new name and gives me the path of the copied image with its new name but I need the actual path.

For example
the actual path is : `/storage/data/image.jpg`
but it returns :  `/storage/data/image_1.jpg`

Here is the code I am using to pick the image :

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
try
{
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
    {
        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium
    });
    if (file == null) return;
    Stream stream = null;
    stream = file.GetStream();
    string file_path = file.Path;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string test = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: if you're picking an image from the device photo gallery, I don't know that there is a canonical path you can rely on.  I don't believe iOS exposes a direct file path to images stored in the image gallery - if it did then you could just harvest every image in their camera roll without permission.

Comment: Do you have duplicated image? if the name of the file is a duplicate then a number will be appended to the end https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#directories-and-file-names